# Duplicate elements in a mutidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been trying, but I cannot figure this myself...

I have a MySQL table that contains info like this (plus an ID column):

```
Artist      Song       Uploader
art1        song1      name1
art2        song2      name2
art1        song1      name3
```

I would like to use php to present this table with this output:

```
Artist      Song       Times uploaded
art1        song1      2
art2        song2      1
```

The main idea is to find the duplicates (artist + song) inside my table.

I have tried using array_count_values() with the variable that contains all the data from the MySQL table. But this outputs this error:

Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! in index.php on line 40

I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks all!

Comment: Honestly dude, what on earth makes you think we know what line 40 is?

Comment: @RUJordan It does not matter, I´m not posting the complete file... line 40 i where the function is used...

Comment: @qalbiol are you sure the variable contains data and its not just a resource ? whats the output when `var_dump` the variable?

Comment: @Phoenix It is data. I can output all its values in a table without problem. I var_dumped the variable and see that there is some charset problems as I am getting words like: AnÃ³nimo (should be Anónimo, spanish). Thanks for the answer, I will try to figure this first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in PHP, do it in your database query

```
SELECT artist, 
       song, 
       count(id) as uploadCount
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY artist, 
          song
```

Let the database do what databases are good at doing

Comment: Ok, true, better use databases, I didn´t know this way... Just new to php, sql... Thanks! This seems to work perfectly!